How to parse request body of POST method in typescript?
We have a backend API which expects below type in the request body.
type taskslistrequest = {
    clientgroupcode: string[];
    startindex: number;
    pagesize: number;
}

This is how I am parsing the request body:
const tasklistreq: taskslistrequest = req.body.taskslistrequest as taskslistrequest;

However, typescript doesn't throw any error if I send below request body from postman.
{
    "taskslistrequest": {
        "clientgroupcode": [
            "AAB",
            "AAC",
            "AAD"
        ],
        "startindex": "0",
        "pagesize": "50"
    }
}

Can you please help me to understand how can I make sure that if there is any type mismatch then it is captured while parsing the request body itself.
I am using:

Typescript - 5.3.3
NodeJS - 20.10.0
Express - 4.18.2


I like to validate my request with joi it would probably look like this:
const fooValidation = Joi.object({
  var1: joi.array().required().items(
    Joi.string())
  var2: Joi.number().required()
  var3: Joi.string()
 })
 
 fooValidation.validate(req.body)

look at the documentation https://joi.dev/

Yes, from last few days I was comparing zod and Joi. Finally, decided to go with Joi.

From what I understand, TypeScript code is compiled to JavaScript code that will be run at runtime, hence it can't perform TypeScript type check at runtime from generated requests. However, you can workaround this by manually checking req.body.taskslistrequest.startindex and req.body.taskslistrequest.pagesize before proceeding with the parsing
if ((typeof req.body.taskslistrequest.pagesize === "number") && (typeof req.body.taskslistrequest.startindex === "number")) {
  const tasklistreq: taskslistrequest = req.body.taskslistrequest as taskslistrequest;
} else {
  // Type mismatch alert
}


This is helpful for couple of fields but what if the request body contains too many (20-30) fields?? There is option to send further filters like services, start date etc. in the request body. Checking type manually will be a nightmare. So, I was looking at a package or OOTB lib to do the type checking on object properties before it maps one object (request body) to other object (our defined type) and throw error on type mismatch.

Enhancing tax_evader answer - creating map for validation might help. (Or if it would be possible to retrieve the map from taskslistrequest type). In case of other types simply add another checks to map and validate function.
map = {
    "clientgroupcode" : "array",
    "startindex": "number",
    "pagesize": "number",
};
    
function validate(entry) {
    const numberRegexp = new RegExp(/^(\d+)$/);

    let isValid = true;
        
    for (const [key, type] of Object.entries(map)) {
        switch(type) {
            case 'number': 
                if(!numberRegexp.test(entry[key])) {
                    isValid = false;
                    console.log("Field " + key + " is not a number");
                }
            break;
                
            case 'array': 
                if(!Array.isArray(entry[key])) {
                    isValid = false;
                    console.log("Field " + key + " is not an array");
                }
            break;

            default:
                isValid = false;
                console.log("Field " + key + " not found");
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}   

validate(req.body.taskslistrequest);


